# How to use global variable inside the html?

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

I wonder why I couldn't find any good example of this:
    Inside the function, person is an object and there is correct values and selectedPerson is a global variable. Don't bother \-signs, that was the way to get those visible here.

```
document.getElementById(heading).innerHTML="<\p><\strong>" + selectedPerson.name+"<strong><\\p>";
```

This is not working and neither this inside the html:

```
<p>
     <strong>
        <script>document.write(selectedPerson.name);</script>
     </strong>
</p>
```

---

```
var selectedPerson;
function person(extra){

var extra_array=extra.split(",");

this.name=extra_array[0];
this.head=extra_array[1];
this.gValue=extra_array[2];
this.weight=extra_array[3];
alert(extra_array[0]+" "+extra_array[1]+" "+extra_array[2] +" "+extra_array[3]);
//alert(this.name" "this.head+" "+extra_array[2] +" "+extra_array[3]);
```

}

```
selectedPerson = new person(extra);
    console.log("**************************extra-------------->" +extra);
```

And the question is: How can I use global variable/Object inside the HTML? I would like to know both ways if there is? Alert is working when using array, but not with this.name etc. How can I use syntax selectedPerson.name inside the HTML?

Thank you!
Sami

Comment: Establish the global variable before it is called. :(

Comment: I [cannot reproduce your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/2SgF5/1/) (although I did fix the errors in the HTML in your string).

Comment: What did you fix? I can't see anything fixed...And yes I create the global variable before the function at the beginning of the code.

Comment: @Sami — I got rid of the bizarre escape characters and turned the extra start tags into end tags.

Comment: OK, I think that it is still quite bizarre, but it is not your fault, it is Stackoverflow's fault :) <\p><\strong>" + selectedPerson.name+"<strong><\\p>

Comment: @Sami — StackOverflow does not add random \ characters and remove / characters from code blocks.

Comment: I did it because otherwise you or nobody else couldn't see the code after innerHTML=" Just try, take those extra /-signs off and the rest will be lost. Of course it should be: document.getElementById(heading).innerHTML="<p><strong>" + selectedPerson.name+"</strong></p>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating `new person()` with `extra` which is `undefined`.

This will error as you try to `split()` it, and `undefined` doesn't have a `split` method.

So `selectedPerson` will be `undefined` as the object will fail to to be created.

Comment: Split is working fine. I can see the correct values in alert. Extra is defined with proper value. The problem is that I can't use the selectedPerson.name inside the html or straight with documentWrite, because I don't know how to :) I can see this as well:console.log("**************************extra-------------->" +extra);

Comment: "Extra is defined with proper value" — It isn't in the code you've shared with us!

Comment: Maybe my bad English, sorry. I tried to tell in here at the beginning of the text: "person is an object and there is correct values". There is correct and proper values, I can see them form the log and from the alerts. I just don't kno how to use those values inside the html.

Comment: @Sami — With the code you have already. There isn't anything wrong with the stuff you showed originally.

Comment: If I switch in the person constructor and add a string to represent *extra*, then [my live example **still** works](http://jsfiddle.net/2SgF5/2/).

Comment: console.log("SelectedPerson-------------->" +selectedPerson);
  console.log("selectedPerson.name-------------->" +selectedPerson.name);
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML="<p><strong>" + selectedCartridge.name+"<\/strong><\/p>";
SelectedPerson-------------->[object Object] index.html:62
selectedPerson.name-------------->222 Rem index.html:63
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
One problem was those escape-marks, I haven't got those!

Comment: It is working now! document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML="<p><strong>" + selectedPerson.name+"<\/strong><\/p>"; One mistake was that I got it without quotation marks like that:getElementById(heading) and the smaller problem was that I missed backslash \-signs as well. Thanks a lot everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing using global variable before it is being declared.

Use declaration at top in your script file

Comment: no i mean do declaration befotre any other script gets loaded and then try

Comment: It is the first line of code in the whole file: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var selectedPerson;
 There is no html, no javascript, nothing before that.

Comment: what selectedPerson is assigned to

Comment: selectedPerson = new person(extra);

Comment: as @Quentin answered 'extra' is undefined

Comment: No it is not: **************************extra-------------->Rem, SPEEDHEAD, 105G, 32kg and I can see every value in alert inside the function. I just don't know how to use those values inside the html from the selectedPerson object. Maybe this is so stupid question that it is almost difficult :) How to show global objects value inside the html-tags.

Comment: wait define extra before using it, then may be u'll understand the mistake

Comment: see the order
at top of script define function person and then try:
selectedPerson = new person(extra);